# Convert & combine strings of format filter[where][id][gt] to object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm sending a query-string to a server in a format resembling [Loopback's Where-Filter](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Where+filter). It's parameter are received like this:

```
{ 'filter[where][id][gt]': '1000',
  'filter[where][price][between][0]': '7',
  'filter[where][price][between][1]': '10' }
```

I want to turn this into a JavaScript-object for further processing.

The format I'm looking to convert it to is this:

```
{ where: { id: { gt: 1000 }, price: { between: [7, 10] } } }
```

What would be the easiest way to do so?

Are there security issues I need to keep in mind?

Comment: It is already a javascript object. You should describe in what format do you need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using lodash you can:

```
var obj = { 'filter[where][id][gt]': '1000',
  'filter[where][price][between][0]': '10',
  'filter[where][price][between][1]': '7' }

var output = {};
_.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    _.set(output, key, obj[key]);
});
output = output.filter; // you have the object you want.
```

Answer (score 1):

In plain Javascript, you could use a regex for retrieving the parts and [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for the creating and stepping through the object.

It generates an array if a key is finite, otherwise an object.

```js
var object = { 'filter[where][id][gt]': '1000', 'filter[where][price][between][0]': '7', 'filter[where][price][between][1]': '10' },
    tree = {};

Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k) {
    var path = k.match(/[^\[\]]+/g),
    last = path.pop();
    path.shift();
    path.reduce(function (r, a, i, aa) {
        return r[a] = r[a] || (isFinite(i + 1 in aa ? aa[i + 1] : last) ? [] : {});
    }, tree)[last] = object[k];
});

console.log(tree);
```